# owl carousel 2 start autoplay when the section visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I want to start the autorun function of owl carousel 2 when i will be in that carousel section. Normally the autorun will not run and when i scroll down and hover over the section the autoplay will start. See code ---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>this is heading section</h1>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1>This is section</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/550x450"/></div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    center: false,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayTimeout: 1000,
    smartSpeed:1000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true
});
$('.section').mouseover(function(e) {
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
})
```

See I use mouseover function to active the function , I mean when i mouseover the section the autoplay need to run but it is not working ... please help me out ...

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO PROJECT HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mgq2L54L/8/)

Comment: First off, the carousel itself is not built!

Comment: hi, @LShetty there is no chance to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you need the following.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true
});

$('.section').on("mouseenter", function(e) {
    owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000);
    //Not owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
})
```

**-[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mgq2L54L/10/)-**

Take a look at the [doc](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) since you've either been using an old version/using non-existent params.

Comment: for carousel v.2 it's `autoplay.play.owl` !